# Jest snapshot test failing due to react navigation generated key

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

My Jest test is failing because of the timestamp in the key being different every time the test is run:

```
 FAIL  ./App.test.js
  ✕ renders without crashing (72ms)

  ● renders without crashing

expect(value).toMatchSnapshot()

Received value does not match stored snapshot 1.

- Snapshot
+ Received

@@ -347,11 +347,11 @@
              "index": 0,
              "isTransitioning": false,
              "key": "StackRouterRoot",
              "routes": Array [
                Object {
-                 "key": "id-1519567169760-0",
+                 "key": "id-1519567814666-0",
                  "routeName": "Menu",
                },
              ],
            },
          }
```

Here is my App.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Menu from './components/Menu';
import List from './components/List';

const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Menu: {
      screen: Menu,
    },
    List: {
      screen: List,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Menu',
  }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return <RootStack />;
   }
}
```

Here is my test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

test('renders without crashing', () => {
  const rendered = renderer.create(<App />).toJSON();
  expect(rendered).toBeTruthy();
  expect(rendered).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Is it possible override the key value or is there a way to ignore key when the test runs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newer versions of jest also support [property matchers](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing#property-matchers) which allow certain parts of the snapshot to be evaluated using a matcher instead of requiring the entire snapshot to be identical.

Here is an example showing a few different approaches to using this feature to solve OP's question:

```js
it('Should ignore route keys in snapshot', () => {
  const testObject = {
    index: 0,
    isTransitioning: false,
    key: 'StackRouterRoot',
    routes: [
      {
        key: `id-${Date.now()}-0`,
        routeName: 'Menu',
      },
      {
        key: `id-${Date.now()}-1`,
        routeName: 'Splash',
      },
    ],
  };

  expect(testObject).toMatchSnapshot({
    routes: [
      {
        key: expect.stringMatching(/id-\d+?-\d/),
        routeName: 'Menu',
      },
      {
        key: expect.stringMatching(/id-\d+?-\d/),
        routeName: 'Splash',
      },
    ],
  }, 'Explicitly list all routes');

  expect(testObject).toMatchSnapshot({
    routes: expect.arrayContaining([
      expect.objectContaining({
        key: expect.stringMatching(/id-\d+?-\d/),
      }),
    ]),
  }, 'Match any route');
});
```

Which produces the following snapshots:

```js
exports[`<App /> Should ignore route keys in snapshot: Explicitly list all routes 1`] = `
Object {
  "index": 0,
  "isTransitioning": false,
  "key": "StackRouterRoot",
  "routes": Array [
    Object {
      "key": StringMatching /id-\\\\d\\+\\?-\\\\d/,
      "routeName": "Menu",
    },
    Object {
      "key": StringMatching /id-\\\\d\\+\\?-\\\\d/,
      "routeName": "Splash",
    },
  ],
}
`;

exports[`<App /> Should ignore route keys in snapshot: Match any route 1`] = `
Object {
  "index": 0,
  "isTransitioning": false,
  "key": "StackRouterRoot",
  "routes": ArrayContaining [
    ObjectContaining {
      "key": StringMatching /id-\\\\d\\+\\?-\\\\d/,
    },
  ],
}
`;
```

Another jest feature I came across recently that might help here is [custom snapshot serializers](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#snapshotserializers-array-string). Using this feature I think you could add a serializer for route objects that would remove the key or replace it with a static value before it is serialized. I can't provide an example right now as I have not yet used this feature, but it seemed worth mentioning.

Comment: I have seen this in the **Jest** documentation but it is not at all clear to me how this would be applied to the asker's problem in the react-navigation tree.

Comment: @KevinvanZyl I think the idea is that for certain properties of a snapshot that are expected to change, you can specify a matcher instead of  expecting it to be the exact same value as when it was taken.

Comment: @KevinvanZyl I have updated my original answer with some custom example code to hopefully explain this better.

Answer (score 2):

You can mock the data that is non-deterministic. https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/snapshot-testing.html#tests-should-be-deterministic

> For example, if you have a Clock component that uses Date.now(), the
>   snapshot generated from this component will be different every time
>   the test case is run. In this case we can mock the Date.now() method
>   to return a consistent value every time the test is run:
>
> Date.now = jest.fn(() => 1482363367071);
>
> Now, every time the snapshot test case runs, Date.now() will return
>   1482363367071 consistently. This will result in the same snapshot
>   being generated for this component regardless of when the test is run.

Comment: where should I put this line?

Comment: You should be able to use it directly in your `it('')` or `test('')` calls. Ie, `it('test', () => { Date.now = fest.fn(() => 123); ...rest of your test... });`

Answer (score 2):

You can override the key value by using a mocked function in your  jest setup file:
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfiles-array

Set the key to always be the same by mocking Date.now to `Date.now = jest.fn(() => 123)` since under the hood react navigation uses this to generate their route keys: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/src/routers/KeyGenerator.js

Answer (score 2):

I have found a completely different solution which I have put as an answer to my own similar question.

[Snapshot test with Jest on nested react-navigation component - Object keys change so Snapshot match fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53448041/snapshot-test-with-jest-on-nested-react-navigation-component-object-keys-chang)

I solved my problem, but not by mocking Date.now which was suggested in many other cases.

Instead I adapted an answer I found on https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2269#issuecomment-369318490 by a user named **joeybaker**.

The rationale for this was given as:

> The keys aren't really important for your testing purposes. What you
>   really care about is the routes and the index.

His code is as follows and assumes the use of actions and reducers in **Redux**:

```
// keys are date and order-of-test based, so just removed them
const filterKeys = (state) => {
  if (state.routes) {
    return {
      ...state,
      routes: state.routes.map((route) => {
        const { key, ...others } = route
        return filterKeys(others)
      }),
    }
  }
  return state
}

it('clears all other routes', () => {
    const inputState = {}
    const action = { type: AUTH_LOGOUT_SUCCESS }
    const state = filterKeys(reducer(inputState, action))
    expect(state.routes).toBe........
})
```

I have adapted this for my case (I do not use **Redux** yet) as follows:

```
test("renders correctly", () => {

  const tree = renderer.create(<StackNavigator />);
  const instance = tree.getInstance();
  const state = filterKeys(instance.state.nav);

  expect(state).toMatchSnapshot();
});

// keys are date and order-of-test based, so just removed them
const filterKeys = (state) => {
  if (state.routes) {
    return {
      ...state,
      routes: state.routes.map((route) => {
        const { key, ...others } = route
        return filterKeys(others);
      }),
    }
  }
  return state;
};
```

The test that gets rendered looks like this:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`renders correctly 1`] = `
Object {
  "index": 0,
  "isTransitioning": false,
  "key": "StackRouterRoot",
  "routes": Array [
    Object {
      "index": 0,
      "isTransitioning": false,
      "routeName": "FluidTransitionNavigator",
      "routes": Array [
        Object {
          "routeName": "SignInOrRegister",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
`;
```